# Warning: requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i am new in android pls help me to fix issue

I have been trying to use android studio 2.0 emulator but I can not run my App on the Emulator. When I Run my App it shows the emulator with following details:

I already try all related **stackoverflow solution** and also reduce ram and HAXM  Memory but i can't fix issue please  help me.

**My Error :**

```
Error : Hax is enabled
WARNING: init: Missing WGL extension WGL_ARB_make_current_read
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Warning: requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M
```

After some time display message :  Launching app

Then avd continues loading and display Android is starting optimizing app

At last Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: you have to change your settings in your AVD.
go to AVD settings and change RAM size 512M instead of 1024M.

Answer (score 0):

open Android studio Window->Select Android Virtual Device Manager
->Chose your device->Click Edit button->Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb in the Memory Options->Save and run the  emulator it will work

Recommended: Else you may use Genymotion Android Virtual Machine:
https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download

Comment: use Genymotion  it's much faster then emulator

Comment: when i work with Genymotion and run it's start working but display only white screen how to fix...?

Comment: can you attach screen shot of it? and set proper device configuration ?@pinalzala